# How to define a new search provider in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, website, search, firefox-3.6

I frequently use [this web site](http://divxplanet.com/) for searching movie subtitles. What I do is to open the page, navigate to the relevant search box, and type in the movie name in it.

[image]

I want to speed up this process by defining a new search provider to achieve this from Firefox's built-in search box.

How can I add this search to Firefox's built-in search engine list?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the add-on [Add to Search Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar/) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your answer. One more question: This does not work on [cdcovers.cc](http://www.cdcovers.cc/). I click on "Add to search bar..." but nothing happens. Any clues?

Comment: Looking at the source, the search on that site seems to make heavy use of javascript, which may be the cause of the problem. This ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/creating_opensearch_plugins_for_firefox ) may help you in writing an OpenSearch plugin for that site, otherwise there are some search plugins for cdcovers.cc listed here (http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?name=cdcovers ).

Comment: The links you gave seem useful. Thanks again.

Comment: I used [this link](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/jsreq.html) and it created cdcovers.cc search provider properly. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider [smart keywords](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/smart%20keywords) search which is built into firefox. Essentially you right click in the search box on a website and select "add a keyword for this search". Set a keyword. Now you can search that site using the keyword followed by your search term in the address bar of the web browser.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your answer, but this does not work on [cdcovers.cc](http://www.cdcovers.cc/). When I right click on the search box, "Add a keyword for this search" does not show up. Even though I add a keyword from the "bookmark properties" window for this site, it performs the search on Google. Any clues?

Comment: @Mehper I wish I knew ):